# MYSQL: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query to search for tags similarity

```
SELECT sites_id
    FROM tags_to_sites
    WHERE tags_id IN (SELECT tags_id FROM tags_to_sites WHERE sites_id= ?)
    AND sites_id!= ?
    GROUP BY sites_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (  SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM  tags_to_sites
    WHERE tags_id IN (SELECT tags_id FROM tags_to_sites WHERE sites_id= ?)
      AND sites_id!= ?
    GROUP BY sites_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3)
```

but i get an error

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
>   than 1 row

anybody knows why?

Comment: Your subquery return 3 rows (by `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3`), and you have to return only 1. Or rewrite your `having` statement to `HAVING COUNT(*) IN `

Comment: good catch! so how do i limit the final array to only 3 results? shoudl I move limit 3 outside the bracket right?

Comment: can you add some data from table and explain what query your want?

Answer (score 0):

the correct query

```
SELECT sites_id
    FROM tags_to_sites
    WHERE tags_id IN (SELECT tags_id FROM tags_to_sites WHERE sites_id= ?)
    AND sites_id!= ?
    GROUP BY sites_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (  SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM  tags_to_sites
    WHERE tags_id IN (SELECT tags_id FROM tags_to_sites WHERE sites_id= ?)
      AND sites_id!= ?
    GROUP BY sites_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 3
```